# Changue color of pointer in TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

Im trying to changue the color of the pointer of my TextFormField, I tried changue the color of the cursor color, but the pointer is in the default color. In android i know how to do but in flutter i don´t see any answers.
Do someone know how to do ? Thanks.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WibZM.png)

Comment: go through this'https://googleflutter.com/flutter-textfield-cursor-color/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cursorColor parameter to do that.

Second Approach, Change MaterialApp theme:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: YourColor,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: i did that but the problem follow

Comment: I think you're using different widget around the Textformfield that overriding the cursor color. Anyway, you change it in the material theme, see my updated answer.